# Remove City from State in a JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to remove the city from the state, that way I can parse the json. 
Not entirely sure what would work. Not sure splice is the correct answer for this as the city could be multiple words.  So a bit at a loss.

Example JSON is

```
[{"Date": "2007", "Description": "descriptive things", "Bleh": "0", "Location": "Chico, California", "Stuff": "1"}, {"Date": "2009", "Description": "descriptive things", "Bleh": "0", "Location": "Mount Vernon, Illinois", "Stuff": "0"}, {"Date": "2009", "Description": "descriptive things", "Bleh": "0", "Location": "Trinidad, Colorado", "Stuff": "1"}]

function locationChart()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'example.json',
        data:
        {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
            {

             })
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far? That might prevent people from downvoting and would help encourage others to try and help you :) -- that is, more than your empty ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope return data is json as you post,if so try return data by `$.each` for loop all object.Split Location by `,` into array.

```
function locationChart()
{
  $.ajax(
     {
      url: 'example.json',
      data:
      {},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data)
        {
         var update_json = [];
         $.each(data,function(i,v){             
            var state = v.Location.split(',')[1];//this will remove city
            v.Location = state; //assign update data to object
            update_json.push(v);
         });      
         console.log(update_json);
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`split(',')` is what you're looking for.

[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

`data[0].Location.split(',')[0]` will get you what's before the comma (i.e. the city). To remove it from the json just say `data[0].Location = data[0].Location.split(',')[1]`, thereby making it only what's after the comma (the State).

Keep in mind that will remove it from the response `data` object, but not from the json file. The change won't reflect elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Sure, thanks. The MDN is a great resource for native JavaScript. I use it every day.